# SQL - Group records together based on value

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have a table with the following values:

```
  some-id   timestamp
 --------- -----------
      1       12:45
      1       12:50
      2        3:13
      2        3:15
      3       11:33
      3       11:50
```

I would like a resulting `SELECT` to return the below:

```
  some-id   timestamp_a   timestamp_b
 --------- ------------- -------------
      1       12:45         12:50
      2        3:13          3:15
      3       11:33         11:50
```

eg. The `timestamp` is grouped by a duplicate `some_id`

Is this possible with SQL?

Comment: What defines which one is `timestamp_a` versus `timestamp_b`?

Comment: It looks like you want `MAX(timestamp)`, `MIN(timestamp)`, and `GROUP BY someid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be just a simple aggregation,

```
select some-id, Min(Timestamp) Timestamp_a, Max(Timestamp) Timestamp_b
from t
group by some-id
```